# How to give a "/" in a column name to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I wish to give a "/" (backslash) in a column name in a dataframe. Any idea how?

I tried following to no avail,

```
tmp1 <- data.frame("Cost/Day"=1:10,"Days"=11:20)
tmp1

     Cost.Day Days
1         1   11
2         2   12
3         3   13
4         4   14
5         5   15
6         6   16
7         7   17
8         8   18
9         9   19
10       10   20
```

I then tried this, it worked.

```
tmp <- data.frame(1:10,11:20)
colnames(tmp) <- c("Cost/Day","Days")
tmp

     Cost/Day Days
1         1   11
2         2   12
3         3   13
4         4   14
5         5   15
6         6   16
7         7   17
8         8   18
9         9   19
10       10   20
```

I would prefer giving the name while constructing the dataframe itself. I tried escaping it but it still didn't work.

```
tmp2 <- data.frame("Cost\\/Day"=1:10,"Days"=11:20)
tmp2
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's going to make referring to the column cumbersome later on. If you really want to do it, look at `check.names`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Need it to show up as a column name in a report. It's the final step so hopefully won't need to refer it again.

Comment: How about just "Cost per Day" or some such?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft There are too many columns. Want to keep it as short as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `check.names=FALSE` in the `data.frame`.  By default, it is `TRUE`.  And when it is `TRUE`, the function `make.names` changes the `colnames`. ie.

```
  make.names('Cost/Day')
  #[1] "Cost.Day"
```

So, try

```
  dat <- data.frame("Cost/Day"=1:10,"Days"=11:20, check.names=FALSE)
  head(dat,2)
  #  Cost/Day Days
  #1        1   11
  #2        2   12
```

The specific lines in `data.frame` function changing the column names is

```
--------
if (check.names) 
    vnames <- make.names(vnames, unique = TRUE)
names(value) <- vnames
--------
```